# Check whether Flash is running in C#

Tags: c#, flash, windows-7, process

I'd like to create a tool that would periodically check whether Flash is running. The only thing I thought of is checking processes, but the flash player plugin process is running even after the tab with Flash content is closed. What are my options?

Comment: Can you see the flash plugin running in Task Manager; is that what you mean?

Comment: @Brian his asking through by c# coding sir g

Comment: @Brian Yes, this is what I mean; the flash process is still in the task manager.

Comment: @JohnNoCookies - Have you looked into the [Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) Method, yet?  (I am assuming that you have).

Comment: @Brian How would I use that to detect whether Flash is running?

Answer (score -1):

is it to check whether ANY flash app is running or whether a specific flash app is running? 
if its the latter then you can do what i did for my flash app. i wrote an xml file to the sandbox which flagged the status of my flash app and where the user was within the flash app. 
not sure if

Comment: I think there is a bit of your answer missing.. Also, what does the xml file do? what sandbox are you talking about? How do you read the status of the flash app? why do you need to know where the user is within the flash app?

Comment: web browser's cannot write to local disk for security reasons, but they are allowed to write to a confined area on the host pc - usually called a sandbox. if you develop a flash app, your app can write an xml file to this confined area. within this xml file you can store info on the status of the flash app and what the user is doing. i had to do this to solve a similar problem before and it worked a treat.